How can we identify which column name got renamed in a dataframe?
Suppose, I;m getting a dataframe with cols - [A,B,C] everyday. Suddenly, next day one of the column got renamed to 'D'.
How can I identify which column got renamed to D? Can we compare data and say which column got renamed?
I tried working with Fuzzy match (ExtractOne), But it compares every column data with all other cols data; which is a time taking process. Is there any better way to handle this situation?

Why not just compare the column names since that is what you are interested in. For example print(set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns)) will show the names of column(s) in df1 which are not in df2. Or else set(df1.columns) ^ set(df2.columns) will show those names in either DF not in the other.

It's not only about the column - we need to identify whether the column is really renamed or its a new column that is added, for that we need to compare the data

To handle this situation more efficiently, you can directly compare the column data instead of using fuzzy matching, which can be slow. Here's a simpler way:
Start by figuring out which columns stayed the same: Compare the previous dataframe's columns with the current one. This narrows down which columns need further checking.
Next, compare the columns that are different: Since one column was renamed, the data in that column should be the same (or very close) to one of the original columns.
This way, you're doing a direct comparison of columns, which is much quicker than fuzzy matching.

When a column is renamed, I capture the column names that are added and deleted. These changes typically indicate a renaming, though it's not always guaranteed. I'm comparing the data in the added and deleted columns, but there's a case where if a column is renamed and a new row is inserted in the middle, the row comparison may not match correctly. This could lead to a misrepresentation of the column name.

Can you just store the names of in the previous day, then compare today's names with previous day and look if any names are missing from yesterday?
You can also create a hash for each column based on its data.
